# Marlin temperature update frequency 3Dprinter

Tags: frequency, temperature, printed

I would like to know at what frequency is the temperature information pulled by the marlin software. I have looked into the code but it insn't obvious to me.

Comment: But you have not provided the code, nor any documentation at all...

Comment: Thought marlin was known, but anyway a link to the code on github : https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/tree/RC/Marlin

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i asked on the github and got a response.

[image: GithubTemperatureMeasurement]

Thanks